# No errors but Go app still doesn't work properly

Tags: http, go, redirect, cookies, localhost

I'm working on a web chat application and I experienced an issue that shouldn't be happening.
In the main.go I have this function:

```
http.Handle("/chat", MustAuth(&templateHandler{filename: "chat.html"}))
```

and I've just built an authentication file (auth.go, still in progress) with a cookie, here it is:

```
package main

import "net/http"

type authHandler struct {
    next http.Handler
}

func (h *authHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    _, err := r.Cookie("auth")
    if err == http.ErrNoCookie {
        //not authenticated
        w.Header().Set("Location", "/login")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
        return
    }
    if err != nil {
        //some other error
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    //success - call the next handler
    h.next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
func MustAuth(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return &authHandler{next: handler}
}
```

The problem is that when I run it and open the localhost page, the cookie doesn't work how it should and doesn't redirect me to the login page as it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made a fully compiling example out of the code you provided - however it does work for me: `lolcalhost:8080/chat` redirects me to `localhost:8080/login`
I suspect your browser may have a cookie "auth" already set.

You can press STRG+SHIFT+I and go to the networking tab to see what is transmitted.
Check there really is no cookie set for you.

Code I tried:

```
package main

import "net/http"

type authHandler struct {
    next http.Handler
}

func ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    _, err := r.Cookie("auth")
    if err == http.ErrNoCookie {
        //not authenticated
        w.Header().Set("Location", "/login")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
        return
    }
    if err != nil {
        //some other error
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    //success - call the next handler
    //h.next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    w.Write([]byte("Hi"))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/chat", ServeHTTP)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try it later, can I contact you so I can give you the full project and let you help me for another thing also? Thanks